# Puppeteer node.js : if class doesn't exist pass blank value in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a page with business listings and get the title, location and website. The issue is that some of these businesses don't have a website. I'm currently using an array of arrays to store the data:

```
[ 
  [websites],
  [titles],
  [locations]
]
```

When exporting the output in excel, I want to pass a blank value to the array of websites when there is no website listed and the URL for those that do have a website. In other words, I want to have something like this:

| Websites | Titles | Locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Website A | Title A | Location A |
| (blank because it doesn't have a website) | Title B | Location B |
| Website C | Title C | Location C |
| ... | ... | ... |

The code I've written so far is the following:

```
async function main(){
  try{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({"headless":false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url), { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }; 
    const businessesPosts = await page.$$eval("[class^='AdvItemBox']", allPosts => allPosts.map(post => [
        post.querySelector(".siteLink.urlClickLoggingClass").href != null 
        ? post.querySelector(".siteLink.urlClickLoggingClass").href 
        : " ", //throws error "Cannot read property 'href' of null"
        post.querySelector("[class^='CompanyName']").innerText, // get the title
        post.querySelector("[class^='AdvAddress']").innerText] // get the location
        ));
        const wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
        const ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(businessesPosts);
        xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,ws);
        xlsx.writeFile(wb, "posts.xlsx");

        await browser.close()

     } catch(e){
          console.log('error',e);
          }
    };
 main();
```

Here's the HTML code of the website's class

```
<a class="siteLink urlClickLoggingClass" target="_blank" product="AdvListing" productid="2419662++1926511++1" href="http://www.test.com">
```

Apparently there's something wrong when trying to insert a condition inside the array.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```js
        post.querySelector(".siteLink.urlClickLoggingClass").href != null
        ? post.querySelector(".siteLink.urlClickLoggingClass").href
        : " ",
```

try:

```js
        post.querySelector(".siteLink.urlClickLoggingClass")?.href ?? " ",
```

See:

- [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: Many thanks!!  Looks like it solved the issue :)